# usage of "much" as an adverb

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence, "Twice as many people as previously estimated are dying of Sepsis."

Then can I change that sentence into this one?
"People are dying of Sepsis twice as much as previously estimated."

If not, is there any other alternative?

Comment: You can check usage by googling "dying twice as much [of/from]",  "dying twice as fast", "dying twice as often", "dying at twice the rate" .... [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dying+twice+as+much%2Cdying+twice+as+fast%2Cdying+twice+as+often&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) also help greatly.  Do you find that using 'much' here is unidiomatic?

Comment: Some of the idiomatic ones are a little strange -- _dying twice as often_ sounds like a vampire fad.